# Set UIWindowScene.PresentationStyle on Scene?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, multitasking, ipados

I have a sample view that I'd love to render as a modal window, similar to the Mail message compose window in iPadOS 15:

```swift
WindowGroup("general.status", id: "create") { authorView  }
    .handlesExternalEvents(matching: ["starlight://create"])
    .commands { TextEditingCommands() }
```

With this setup via `handlesExternalEvents(matching:Set<String>)`, I can get a window to open using `openURL` with a custom identifier, and I can see the modal option in the multitasking menu. However, when opening this window, it still appears as a full-screen scene. I noticed that in "Take your iPad apps to the next level (WWDC21)", you can set a presentation style for a window in UIKit by setting the presentation style to `UIWindowScene.PresentationStyle.prominent`. However, I can't find anything equivalent to this in SwiftUI. Is there a way I can do this in SwiftUI, or call some UIKit code to set the WindowGroup (or the `authorView`) with that activation condition?

I've initially asked this on the developer forums at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/700820 and both r/SwiftUI and r/iOSProgramming, but I'd like to cover my bases and ask here, too, if someone knows.

Comment: why don't you just bind a `.sheet` to your topmost view and trigger it from somewhere?

Comment: I can use `.sheet` to trigger it like that, but then doing it this way prevents the user from dragging that window out into a separate view, which defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reached out to Apple via a TSI about this particular issue. As of the current release of SwiftUI, this isn't possible. They recommend I use the `.sheet` modifier instead and drop the split window capability. Otherwise, I can create a UISceneDelegate and use UIKit APIs directly:

```swift
let options = UIWindowScene.ActivationRequestOptions()
options.preferredPresentationStyle = .prominent
let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: SecondSceneDelegate.sceneUserActivityType)
userActivity.targetContentIdentifier = SecondSceneDelegate.sceneUserActivityType

UIApplication.shared.requestSceneSessionActivation(nil,
    userActivity: userActivity,
    options: options,
    errorHandler: nil)
```